# How To check if string includes in another TASM

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, offset, tasm

I am trying to check if a string includes another string in TASM. I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
DATASEG
str1 db "I Love The World$"
str2 db "Do You Love Me??$"
str3 db "I Don't like ya!$"
lst dw 3 dup(?)
check db "Love"
LengthOfCheck dw 4
strLength dw 16
cntr1 dw 0
includesArray dw 3 dup(?)
CODESEG
start:
    mov [lst], offset str1
    mov [lst+1], offset str2
    mov [lst+2], offset str3
    xor si, si
    mov ax, 0
    mov si, 0 
    mov bx, 0
    mov [cntr1], 0 ;
        CheckInclude:
            mov si, [cntr1]
            mov di, [lst+si] ;moves the string offset
            add di, bx
            mov si, offset check ;again, for the includment
            add si, ax
            mov cl, [si]
            cmp cl, [byte ptr di]
            je CheckNext
            jne MoveFrd
            CheckNext:
            inc ax
            cmp ax, [LengthOfCheck]
            je Match
            MoveFrd:
            inc bx
            cmp bx, [strLength]
            je nextString
            ExitL:
        jmp CheckInclude
        Match:
        mov si, [cntr1]
        mov dx, [lst+si]
        mov [includesArray+si], dx
        nextString:
        inc [cntr1]
```

*the code is just a try. How Can I fix it? I want to check if a string includes the "check" and have the offsets in the "IncludesArray".

Comment: If you want to find a working example, search for `strstr`, the name of the C library function that does this.  (Or with explicit-length strings, `memmem`).  Of course you'll have to wade through lots of complex optimized implementations, and fancy algorithms (like Boyer Moore).  I'm sure there are some examples of simple implementations in x86 asm somewhere, though.

Comment: For your case, "doesn't work" isn't enough detail for us to spot the problem easily.  It's not a [mcve].  http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/.  Also, there's nothing after `inc [cntr1]`, so if execution ever reaches that point then you just fall off into running garbage as instructions, no wonder it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mov [lst], offset str1
> mov [lst+1], offset str2
> mov [lst+2], offset str3
> ```

All of these offsets are **word-sized** values that you mistakenly store at **byte-sized** locations!

You correctly defined *lst* to hold words when you wrote `lst dw 3 dup(?)`.
Then also use it that manner...

Don't forget that your *cntr1* variable needs to step by 2.

In summary these are the changes:

```
    mov [lst], offset str1
    mov [lst+2], offset str2
    mov [lst+4], offset str3
```

and

```
    add [cntr1], 2
```